# Internal and External IP Addresses with an SSL Certificate

Tags: web-server, ssl, ip, ssl-certificate, nat

I'm setting up a web server that has an internal IP address and an external IP address.

```
e.g. Browsers on the network request mysite.example.com and get 192.168.200
Browsers outside the network request mysite.example.com and get 74.125.127.103
```

I want to buy and install a certificate for SSL.  How can I set this up so that both internal and external traffic is secured with a certificate?  Do I need more than one certificate?  Is it possible for the certificate to be valid for both IP addresses?

Comment: i'm sorry but why would you want the SSL on your internal network ?

Comment: @Prix I'm sorry but why _wouldn't_ you want SSL on an internal network?

Comment: because it is a internal network ? are you expecting your employeers to be running things like wireshark or w/e and steal your data ?

Comment: @Prix: Nope.  I'd expect pen-testers and intruders to be running things like wireshark or w/e (whatever that is).  The fact that employees can't usefully do so either is merely a side benefit.

Comment: which would make things useless if there is a hole on the external site but not on the internal ... so your focus should be testing as a proper user from the external view.

Comment: @Prix, I don't want passwords or sensitive data to be passed in clear text - ever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The certificate is checked against the domain name, not the ip. So if you set your webserver to listen for ssl connections on both IPs for the same domain name then you are fine.

Comment: I would say that the implicit answer here is: Ensure that whatever domain name the certificate is for resolves to the appropriate IP address from internal and external hosts.  You can do this by running internally a DNS server for your internal hosts that essentially overrides the DNS system available externally.